# How do I clear the checkbox check? The value is being cleared

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have two checkboxes which help filter data. 
I have a function which clears the filter, but the checkboxes remain checked.

I tried ngModel, but with no success.

```
<label class="filterlable" for="">Other:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <label><input id="CPRBox" type="checkbox" [value]="3" [checked]="CPRBox" (change)="includeOthers(3)">&nbsp;CPR Certified&nbsp;</label>
                    <label><input id="NotaryBox" type="checkbox" [value]="2" [checked]="NotaryBox" (change)="includeOthers(2)">&nbsp;Notary&nbsp;</label>
```

This sets the value when the box is clicked:

```
includeOthers(id): void {
    const index = this.otherArray.indexOf(id);
    if (index == -1) {
      this.otherArray.push(id);
    } else {
      this.otherArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.addQueryParams({ other: this.otherArray.length > 0 ? this.otherArray.toString() : null })
  }
```

This clears the filter, but the box(es) remain checked.

```
clearFilters() {
    this.otherArray = [];
    this.CPRBox = false;
    this.NotaryBox = false;
  }
```

When clearFilters() runs, the checkboxes should no longer be checked.

Right now, the filters are cleared, but the boxes remain checked. Which means, when the user clicks on the boxes a 2nd time, the filters are enabled, but the boxes are not checked, leading to a confusing state of the filter.

Comment: You say "I tried ngModel, but with no success.", but can you specify what you tried and why it didn't work? Also, in your 'includeOthers' method, you're not changing the state of the CPRBox or NotaryBox variables in it. Can you provider a plunker?

Comment: a checkbox has only two values, true or false. Use only [checked] or [value] not both

Comment: <input id="CPRBox" type="checkbox" ngModel="CPRBox" (change)="includeOthers(3)">

Sets the boxes to checked on startup

Comment: created two variable: 
    public CPRCheck = false;
    public NotaryCheck = false;

Then, in the html
<input id="CPRBox" type="checkbox" (value)="CPRCheck" (change)="includeOthers(3); CPRCheck = !CPRCheck">

clearFilters()  - is set this.CPRCheck=false;

Still not seeing any change in the visible status of the checkbox

Comment: <input id="CPRBox" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="CPRCheck" (change)="includeOthers(3); CPRCheck = !CPRCheck">

This at least changes the value of this.CPRCheck every time the box is clicked.